# knockout.js id handling bug?

Tags: knockout.js

I was wondering if any of you have experienced the following issue and maybe knowing a workaround for it.

If I have a 'foreach' iteration in a ko template and trying to use the 'with' context modifier, ko fails to process the first item of the iteration (yes, only the first one) if the 'with' tries to bond to a property called 'id'.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rG5Xw/8/

If you run it, it will not display the first item, but if you change the inner virtual element's 'with' statement to 'name' then it'll work as expected. Pretty annoying... :S

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An even more simple example shows that the problem is caused because ko handling zeros wierd and whenever you try to create a 'with' context change to a property which contains a single zero number it'll fail:
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/rG5Xw/9/
if you change the value of the view model's 'item' property to zero, nothing will be rendered inside the scope of the 'with' statement...

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about.. your fiddle works fine showing all 3 items, and nothing is called 'id'. If I change the 'name' to 'id' it still [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/rG5Xw/10/). same thing with your 2nd fiddle

Comment: @antishok : "if you change the value of the view model's 'item' property to zero, nothing will be rendered inside the scope of the 'with' statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` is meant to be used with objects. So it does a simple check of truthiness which considers zero to be false. You can get around this by converting the number to a string: http://jsfiddle.net/rG5Xw/11/

Edit: Here is a replacement for `with` based on my [`withlight`](https://github.com/mbest/knockout/issues/9#issuecomment-3378765) that doesn't do any checking of the value (example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/rG5Xw/12/):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['mywith'] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var bindingValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var innerContext = bindingContext['createChildContext'](bindingValue);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.mywith = true;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i knew that it works with strings and also with any other data, including numbers. except of course zero. i do not see the point of checking "truthiness" instead of checking if the value is undefined. also i do not see why there is nothing rendered despite the wrapping html element. it should not iterate at all, or it should, but then handle the data as empty, not the whole content. and also it should handle any data, zero definitely, but also undefinieds and so on.

Comment: I added a custom binding that you might find useful in your case.

Comment: very good idea indeed to use custom bindings in place of with bindings - works perfectly, thank you :)